# How to change flutter gradient svg color with blendmode.color but keep background transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class TestScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/business_card/Frame.svg',
          colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.color),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I use this I can change the SVG color from red gradient to blue gradient but I'm getting background color as well. how to remove this background color

[image: This is after i changed the color to blue with BlendMode.coloris the original SVG]

I tried BlendMode.srcIn options so I can change the color with a transparent background, but it will be a solid color, not a gradient, so I want to use BlendMode.Color but when I use BlendMode.color I'm getting a background color as well

Comment: At the end of the day this could be a bit of a guessing game as to what you expect, so I'll just link the [relevant docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode.html) and let you decide. Maybe just `src`?

Comment: I want to change the color and keep the gradient so that when I use BlendMode.Color it change with a background color transparent into a solid color i want to keep it transparent

Comment: this is how it's look when i change color https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KEkehhjPf1axSeYS_wiOEexCHJKxKrQ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Right so I think you want `dstIn` as a BlendMode

Comment: Thank you for your replay but not dstIn no change anything it will remain as original here is an image link to explain more clearly what I'm expecting 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lcjoQOeNrXL78QVX2bdHm85hf4dw3WXf/view?usp=sharing